# Change CSS grid-column when changes the num of rows

Tags: css, gridview, flexbox

I have a grid container with three cells. I have applied this CSS to the container:

```
margin: 0 auto;
display: grid;
gap: 0;
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(280px, 1fr));
justify-items: stretch;
align-items: stretch;
```

When the screen width gets smaller, the third cell goes to a second row. But I want that cell to extend to the whole width like this image:

[image: Wanted]

Is that possible someway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do such a thing with flex-box:
html

```
<body>
  <div style="background-color: blue;"></div>
  <div style="background-color: green;"></div>
  <div style="background-color: red;"></div>
</body>
```

css

```
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
div {
  flex-basis: 280px;
  height: 280px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

`flex-wrap: wrap;` On the flex container will allow items to wrap when they don't fit in the screen.
`flex-grow: 1;` On the flex item will ensure the items grow to fit the available width.